# Attach a ZIP file from /raw to an Email Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to attach a ZIP file that is in **res/raw** as an attachment to an email intent ?

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Copy it to a file on external storage, or
- Create a `ContentProvider` that can serve it straight from the `InputStream` you get from the raw resource

From there, `EXTRA_STREAM` should work, though there may be some email clients that only support `file:///` `Uri` schemes, and not `content://` schemes.

Comment: I tried a Uri scheme with `Uri uri = Uri.parse ("android.resource://com.example.myclass/raw/myfile");` though it sent it as a .file extension instead of ZIP. And adding a .zip extension to myfile sent nothing. Anyway around this ?

Comment: @Traxex1909: Few apps are likely to support `android.resource` schemes. "Anyway around this ?" -- follow the instructions in my answer.